# PHP 7.3 glob pattern to return files if does NOT match pattern

Tags: php, glob

I want to return the list of files that does not match a pattern in a path so I can delete them.

Files are in below directory:

```
"/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/"
```

Files that I want to keep are named as such:

```
"e-Calendar_Test-[date and time here].csv"
```

They start with `"e-Calendar_Test-"`, have a `date in the middle` and end with `".csv"`

Below pattern matches the above criteria:

```
glob("/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/e-Calendar_Test*.csv")
```

I want to return files that do NOT match that. I have tried few things:

```
"^(?!/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/e-Calendar_Test)*.csv"
"/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/(^(?!e-Calendar_Test))*.csv"
```

And few more but nothing seems to return what I want.

Comment: Please show the code which you use to list the files and not just the regex you are trying.

Comment: [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch) or [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) might be better options if unversed with regex, or `*` placeholder patterns really suffice.

Comment: What do you mean with `return files that doesn't match that`? Not match the path or filenames that don't end on .csv or files that don't start with `e-Calendar_Test`? Does the format of the date and time matter?

Comment: @NigelRen ... I am using glob()

Comment: @mario ... I am using glob()

Comment: @Thefourthbird ... as stated in the question date formate does not matter, only the first part and the last part are important.

Comment: @DanielPurPur If you want to use the negative lookahead `(?!` variant, try `^(?!/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/e-Calendar_Test.*\.csv).+$` See https://regex101.com/r/1JO8hz/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird ... I am afraid that did not work but thank you for responding.

Comment: `glob` doesn't support regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob` doesn't support Regular Expressions.  Using a `glob` pattern, just compute the difference of all files and the files that match your pattern.  You can adjust the `*` with the correct number of `?` or whatever for the date:

```
$result = array_diff(glob("/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/*.csv"),
                     glob("/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/e-Calendar_Test-*.csv"));
```

Replace `*.csv` with `*.*` in the first `glob` if you want all files regardless of extension.

Comment: @AbraCadabra preg_grep returns `Warning: preg_grep(): Unknown modifier 'w' ` but second one worked.

Comment: Before your edits I didn't know you used `glob` and you asked for regex, so ignore the `preg_grep` unless you have a regex pattern.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the best at avoiding the regex hell ! Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe an expression similar to,

```
^\/var\/www\/servername\/directory\/subdir_level1\/(?!e-Calendar_Test[^.\r\n]*).*\.csv$
```

might be desired here.

#### Test

```
$re = '/^\/var\/www\/servername\/directory\/subdir_level1\/(?!e-Calendar_Test[^.\r\n]*).*\.csv$/m';
$str = '/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/e-Calendar_Test2019-1-1-11-11-12.csv
/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/e-Calendar_Test2019-1-1-11-11-12.csv
/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/something_else.csv';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(62) "/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/something_else.csv"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KkdA7b/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/KkdA7b/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Hey Emma thanks for your response but it returned `array (size=0)` .....   I tried this code `$allFiles = glob("/var/www/servername/directory/subdir_level1/*");  $re = '/^\/var\/www\/servername\/directory\/subdir_level1\/(?!e-Calendar_Test[^.\r\n]*).*\.csv$/m'; $matches = preg_grep($re, $allFiles);
var_dump($matches);`